# Why does HTML file not open from web browser?

Tags: html, applet

I am having trouble with getting my applet to work on an HTML page. Just a forewarning, I know very little HTML, so if you could go slowly, that would be great. So I made a .html file in Google code, with the intent of it being able to display my applet (because Google sites can't) following the tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFbu8FgK8x4

Because I had a problem with textEdit saving my file as 'page.html.txt', when I really only wanted 'page.html', I made the file itself on google sites and set it's directory to page.html. Unlike to tutorial, though, when I went to the file, I just saw the text of the html, instead of my applet, or even an error message. Here is the link to the code base:
http://wierd0games.googlecode.com/svn/page.html

Here is my HTML, if you don't want to open the above link to see it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Under</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="Main.class" archive="UnderLudumDare.jar" width=300 height=168>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

So why is it not opening as it did in the tutorial? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I made the file differently? Also, I am making the assumption that having the directory to the file be page.html makes it an html file, correct?

Comment: Please expand your assumption (last sentence). It doesn't make a lot of sense at the moment.

Comment: I saved the file as title.html. I made the assumption that by saving that file with a .html extension, it was to be read as an html file. Is this not correct logic, and there is something else that I have to do to make it into an html file, or is it an html file just from doing that?----  That was the original question, but I am now about 90% sure that what I had originally done was not causing the problem, because I got notepad++, and made sure it was, and although the applet opens from my computer, it does not from online. This is another question entirely, though, so I will ask it elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see between yours and theirs is that theirs doesn't contain the 'close applet' tag.

Comment: Yeah, google code gave me an error message, but it went away when I put the close tag in. Is how I made the file a legitimate way to do so?

Comment: @WiErD0 well, I would say yeah but one thing missing from the very top of the page which shouldn't really matter is `<!DOCTYPE html>` also instead of closing the applet tag like this `</applet>` try ending it like this... `<applet code="Main.class" archive="UnderLudumDare.jar" width="300" height="168"/>`